# how to search closest date in the table after a given date using hql

Tags: mysql, date, hql

I want to search closest dates and its data records from the table after a given date using hql.

I've database table named timetable

```
+-------------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+----------+
| timeTableId | date       | hospital           | time                | doctorId |
+-------------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+----------+
|           1 | 2017.03.02 | Medix Care,Marad   | 9.30 am to 10.30 am |        3 |
|           2 | 2017.03.02 | Medix Care,Marad   | 3.30 to 5.30        |        3 |
|           3 | 2012.03.02 | Medix Care,Marad   | 03.30 to 04.30      |        2 |
|           4 | 2017.05.03 | Medix Care,Marad   | 11.25 to 12.25      |        5 |
|           5 | 2012.03.20 | Medix Care,Marad   | 12.30 to 01.30      |        4 |
|           6 | 2012.12.12 | Medix Care,Gacko   | 12.30 to 02.25      |        6 |
|           7 | 2012.12.12 | Medix Care,Marad   | 12.30 to 02.25      |       10 |
|           8 | 2017.06.07 | Medix Care,Marad   | 11.30 to 12.30      |        1 |
+-------------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

How to write hql query for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT MIN(date)
FROM (SELECT date
      FROM timetable
      WHERE GIVEN_DATE >= date) X
```